# Java - JDBC insert in batch status -2 but records present in DB

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to insert records into an Oracle database with JDBC connection but when I look the statuses it shows -2 but all those records are present in the DB:

```
int[] statuses = pstmt.executeBatch()
```

So in that above statuses list containing all -2 values, but I think as per the API less than 0 indicates failed to execute right....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`Statement` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), the constant `SUCCESS_NO_INFO` is defined as -2.  This means "The constant indicating that a batch statement executed successfully but that no count of the number of rows it affected is available."  So, it did execute right.